# How to get the current route from iOS' MapKit?

Tags: ios, maps, mapkit

Is there any way via the public API to get the current route that is being used in Apple Maps?

That is, a user is currently navigating a route via Apple Maps and switches to my app. Is there any way for me to know the route currently in use? Or at least, the current destination?

Comment: No there isn't one out there. That means messing around with apple apps, and that's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only pass data to the maps app. It does not work the other way, so I don't believe you could retrieve information about the current route.